# How to skip error of Get-ChildItem returning Access denied

Tags: powershell, access-denied, get-childitem

I have a problem with my powershell script, i'm trying to find a file in a folder recursivly. The folder where i am looking is %temp%. Unfortunatly in this folder, there is some folder protected by admin right. Then when i am using Get-ChildItem, it return nothing exept an error (UnauthorizedAccessException).

Here is my code :

```
$path= (Get-ChildItem -path $ENV:TEMP -force -Recurse -Include logMyApp.txt).FullName
```

I also tryed with -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue but it does not work.

Thank you for your time :)

Edit : Trying to say Hello, but it does not work, stackoverflow policy ?

Comment: Use `-Filter` instead of `-Include` and then try with `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` again :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Omg you saved me many hours ! Thank you !

Comment: I don't think the access denied part matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Avoid combining the `-Recurse` and `-Include`/`-Exclude` parameters when using `Get-ChildItem` against the `FileSystem` provider - they are not mutually exclusive in a *technical* sense, but their behavior is partially redundant (`-Include`/`-Exclude` tries to recurse the file tree independently) and this can sometimes lead to unexpected, buggy and slow enumeration behavior.

For simple inclusion patterns, use `-Filter` in place of `-Include`:

```bsh
$path = (Get-ChildItem -path $ENV:TEMP -force -Recurse -Filter logMyApp.txt -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).FullName
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Been fighting this for a few days now and this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!